# Flag comments for deletion when suggestion is implemented?

Tags: discussion, flags, comments

It's very common that other users comment and suggest ways to improve your answer. In almost all such cases, the user gets credited in the answer ("Saved 6 bytes thanks to ... ").

A lot of those comments are removed by the user, while many are kept, at least for a while.

Is it OK / a good thing to flag such comments as obsolete, if proper credit is given? I've done this a few times on other people's answers, (and the flags are always accepted), but I sometimes want to do this on my own answers as well. I'm not sure if that is considered rude, or if it's a good thing to clean up the comment sections.

Comment: [Closely related.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5431/8478) (Although that one asks about deleting your own comment instead of flagging others.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, feel free to flag those comments whenever you see them. The important part of your question is

> if proper credit is given

I'd hesitate to delete a suggestion if that leaves no trace of who actually came up with it.