# Flag question comments for deletion when suggestion is implemented?

Tags: discussion, challenges, flags, comments

Related to [Flag comments for deletion when suggestion is implemented?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7586/flag-comments-for-deletion-when-suggestion-is-implemented).

The above question specifically addresses obsolescence flagging and deletion of comments to *answers*.  What about the same question, but directed at challenge questions instead of challenge answers?

Specifically if a comment is made on a question that requires a correction and that correction has been implemented, is it good/OK to flag that comment as obsolete?

Should the commenting user be credited in the question?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, but don't be hasty. Even after the author edits the question in response, the comments are still valuable in certain scenarios:

- The question was closed as unclear (or is headed that way). In that case, as someone who uses the reopen review queue I want to see the comments because they help me understand why the question was opened and to form my own assessment as to whether it has been sufficiently clarified. I've seen cases of questions which were closed as unclear and then reopened by five votes when there were issues raised in the comments which I didn't consider to be clarified at all.
- If I made the request for clarification, I can't always remember exactly what I said. Being able to reread it helps me understand the response and decide whether a follow-up comment is needed.

Comment: Agreed. As an aside, it's good to note though that the moderators don't blindly delete flagged comments; we (or at least I and I assume the others) look at the flagged comment, the question, and the other comments to ensure that the flagged comment actually *is* obsolete before deleting.

Comment: @Alex, I did assume that, but you're right that it's worth stating.

Comment: I figured you knew that, I just mentioned it for completeness ;)

Comment: I must say I frequently insert a link to the comment in the edit message. Therefore I dislike deleting comments because it renders my link given in the revision history inaccessible. According to my understanding raising a (red) flag is really limited to “dangerous” content (spam, insults, etc.) not for legitimate content. We do not have to _artificially_ keep flag reviewers busy.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I'd say go ahead and flag them. We like to see attribution for improvements on answers, such as golfing suggestions, but I don't think this carries over to questions. The comments on questions tend to be about clarification or making sure it complies with our standards. In that case I think once the suggestion has been incorporated into the question and the comment is obsolete, it's fine to flag and delete it even if the commenter was not mentioned in the question. This seems to be common practice so far.